# Copy data from active workbook to new rows in statistics workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make at button in a worksheet that does the following:

1. Copies the values of cells D9:D20 in a current worksheet - named "userinput"
2. Inserts the copied values in another (not open) excel-file called statistics.xlsx on a worksheet called "stats". The values should be appended on a new row in the columns B to M. (like a new post in a database)

I found this code on "Windows secrets" which looks like it can do what I need, but I do not know how to make it work. Hope some genius can help me:

```
    Public Sub TransferData()
    '----------------------------------------------
    'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim I As Integer, J As Integer
    FilePath = "E:\statistics.xlsx"
    '----------------------------------------------
    'CHECK IF STATISTICS FILE IS OPEN
        '------------------------------------------
        'OPEN- SCHEDULE RECHECK
        If FileAlreadyOpen(FilePath) = True Then
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "TransferData"
            Worksheets("userinput").CommandButton1.Enabled = False
            Worksheets("userinput").CommandButton1.Caption = "Saving... Please wait"
        '------------------------------------------
        'CLOSED- OPEN STATISTICS WORKBOOK AND COPY DATA
        Else:
            Workbooks.Open (FilePath)
'this row is showing up red in my VB editor - I also need the current worksheet to work without a specific filename....            
With Workbooks("statistics.xlsx").Worksheets("Stats NewRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Workbooks("Flat File.xlsm").Activate    
            LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

            'the following code I need to change to my needs:
            For I = 2 To LastRow
                For J = 1 To 7
                    .Cells(NewRow, J) = Cells(I, J)
                Next J
            NewRow = NewRow + 1
            Next I
            End With
        '------------------------------------------
        'SAVE, AND CLOSE GLOBAL WORKBOOK
            Worksheets("userinput").CommandButton1.Enabled = True
            Worksheets("userinput").CommandButton1.Caption = "Transfer Data"
            Workbooks("statistics.xlsx").CloseChanges:=True
            MsgBox "Global Journal updated"
        End If
    End Sub


    Function FileAlreadyOpen(FullFileName As String) As Boolean
    'http://www.exceltip.com/files-workbook-and-worksheets-in-vba/determine-if-a-file-is-in-use-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html
    Dim f As Integer
        f = FreeFile
        On Error Resume Next
        Open FullFileName For Binary Access Read Write Lock Read Write As #f
        Close #f
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            FileAlreadyOpen = True
            Err.Clear
        Else
            FileAlreadyOpen = False
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following code will do what you are wanting, simply check and replace sheet names to your desired ones:

```
Sub TransferData()
    Dim xRet As Boolean
    Dim FilePath As String
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("userinput").Range("D9:D20").Copy
    'above copy the range to transfer
    FilePath = "E:\statistics.xlsx"
    'set the path to the file
    xRet = IsWorkBookOpen(FilePath)
    'check if workbook is open
    If Not xRet Then 'if not open do the following
        Workbooks.Open (FilePath)
    End If
    'transfer data below
    With Workbooks("statistics.xlsx").Worksheets("Stats")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        ID = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("userinput").Range("E3")

        For icounter = 1 To LastRow
            If .Cells(icounter, 1) = ID Then FoundID = icounter 'loop to find the E3/ID
        Next icounter

        If FoundID <> "" Then 'if found
            .Range("B" & FoundID).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
            .Range("A" & FoundID) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("userinput").Range("E3")
        Else 'if not found then add to next free row
            .Range("B" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
            .Range("A" & LastRow + 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("userinput").Range("E3")
        End If
    End With
    FoundID = ""
Workbooks("statistics.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(Name As String) As Boolean
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWb = Application.Workbooks.Item(Name)
    IsWorkBookOpen = (Not xWb Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: Can you help me with adding a bit more data? - I would like to also copy the contents of cell E3 in the user input sheet to column A in the statisitics.

Comment: @JesperKindtLarsen Updated my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: If I have the statistics file opne I get an error: Runtime 1004: PasteSpecial method of Range class failed and this line in my debygger is highligthed:

Comment: .Range("D" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

Comment: OK - so the latest code you made would not work when the statistics file is open right?

Comment: It does work whether it's open or closed, I've tested both situations and it does do what you expected, I'm not sure what error you are getting, but I don't seem to be getting any issues...

Comment: Strange - but I can live with that for now. One last thing: would it be possible to make a check on cell E3, so that if it exist in the stats file it would overwrite the row instead of adding a new row?

Comment: @JesperKindtLarsen Updated my answer to replace the row if E3 found in statistics

Comment: Something is wrong - I cannot make it work if E3 is found, it just adds a line anyway. Can you help once more?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/13rEo4F5Ib5XxuxEPkgmi_R1sQmxKEhdtG2zrKDAY1Mg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You should have access now

Comment: @JesperKindtLarsen I've added comments to your document, if you have any further questions, don't hesitate to contact me, I believe it was adding another row because you were looking for the ID in Column A, where it seems like you are storing it in Column C.

Comment: Thank you - I really appreciate your help.